# How to create two-week recurring alarms and reminders?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, reminders, alarm

I have many events that recur on two-week time spanned schedules.  For example, I have several things that happen based on a two-week period where these things repeat on: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Saturday, Sunday, Thursday, Friday... and then starts over.

Here's a visual example, of what some repeating events could be in a two-week schedule (I left off AM/PM as this is just to give some visual help and doesn't reflect the precision of a real schedule):
[image]

It seems that there are a lot of calendars that have the weekly repeating option for days, including the iOS Clock.app, but I really need to set these times out within a two-week pattern as you can see that keeps repeating forever.

Is there a calendaring mechanism on macOS and iOS that facilitates creating indefinitely recurring alarms and reminders on such two-week rotations?

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to how this is organized. What do you consider a 'week' since the days are logically out of order?

Comment: Sorry, starting with Monday being first day of week in my calendar system. So weeks for me go: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday. The repetition is peculiar, but that's how my events and needed alarms repeat.

Comment: Google Calendar allows you to arbitrarily set Saturday, Sunday or Monday as the first day of the week. Does this help?

Comment: Not really, but thanks. I've added a sample image of an example of 2 weeks and with a pattern of how some times could potentially repeat.

Comment: I noticed you updated the question since I posted an answer.  I see you have several time entries per day... are these *also* repeats of the same event or are they different events.  In other words is it "do task 1" at 6:45am and the 7:00am appointment is to "do task 2" (or is it task 1 repeated at 6:45, 7:00, 1:30, 4:45, and 8:50)?

Comment: @TimCampbell some of these these are different events, but a couple of these *could* be considered repeats...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app you are looking for is [Due](https://www.dueapp.com) which can set up repeating reminders as you have described, AND (most importantly) it can repeat its reminder alarm every X minutes until it is marked "done" (at which point it will reset for the next occurrence). I use this for reminding me to take out the trash, which needs to be done every other Wednesday, for example.

Comment: Well you have absolutely brought a degree of peace to my life.  It has been so hard working with some of these rotating schedules I have to deal with.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Both macOS and iOS support "custom" repeat intervals that are somewhat flexible.

Based on reading your clarification, it doesn't sound like you need anything beyond a simple 2-week repeat interval per event but you may need more than one event *if* the days for the event occurrences in even-numbered weeks are not the same as the days for the event occurrences in odd-numbered weeks.

When creating a new event (see image below), select the **repeat** option.  On the *repeat* menu, select the **Custom...** option.  Set the frequency to weekly, but set the repeat interval to 2 weeks and then select the day(s) of the week for that particular event.

In the image below I repeat the event on just one day per week, but it is possible to select multiple days.

If an event occurs on one set of days in odd number weeks (week 1, 3, 5, etc.) but it occurs on different days in event number weeks (week 2, 4, 6, etc.) then you would likely need to clone your event from week one to create a new event for week two ... and then set the repeats for those at 2-week frequencies.

[image: Custom Calendar Repeat Timing]

Comment: Yes, I have thought about going down this path, but one problem I've had is that reminders in Calendar on macOS and iOS do not seem to be "aggressive" enough on the sound / repetition front. It seems that the alarms are quite tame and I really need something that will allow me to pick a custom sound that will repeat until recognized - or at least a one time sound that is custom defined so as to recognize what the reminder is for, etc.

Comment: You can customize alerts and... custom alerts can launch applications.  For example... if you pick music from your iTunes library... it will launch iTunes and start playing the track.  I've used calendar events to launch Automator processes (although launchd can also launch applications based on schedules).

Comment: That's not a bad idea.  I guess I could find a small audio playing app that starts fast and would play a defined sound or perhaps fiddle with Automator.  I guess the problem I'm left with now is how to do this on iOS, which is the other half of my question...